# Print same position in soccer table if the points are the same

Tags: python

I work on a soccer table program and the user should be able to write some scores and then print a table for it. All the teams and their data (like how many matches they have played and how many points they have etc.) are objects in a list. This list is sorted by how many points the team have before it prints it out. If the points are the same, it sorts by some other stuff and last by their name:

```
teamData.sort(key = lambda x: (-x.points, -x.goalDifference, -x.goalsForward, x.name))
```

This works exactly like I want. When I print the list I do like this:

```
position = 1
for team in teamData:
    print(position, end = ": ")
    print(team)
    position += 1
```

(`teamData` is the variable that stores all the team objects)

the output can look like this:

```
    1: TeamA,1,1,0,0,2,0,2,3
    2: TeamB,1,1,0,0,2,0,2,3
    3: TeamC,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
```

The problem is that (in this case) `teamA` and `teamB` have exactly the same data, and therefore, I want the output to look like this:

```
    1: TeamA,1,1,0,0,2,0,2,3
    1: TeamB,1,1,0,0,2,0,2,3
    3: TeamC,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just memorize the previous team:

```
old_position, old_team = 0, None
for position, team in enumerate(teamData, 1):
    # I use enumerate() so I can change the position variable.

    if old_position and '''old_team and team compare to the same rank''':
        position = old_position
    else:
        old_position, old_team = position, team

    print(position, team, sep=': ')
```